# Specify center of rotation in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, rotate

I have four shapes that make up a circle. I've grouped them and I'm trying to rotate them together. But instead of rotating all object together as a circle, all four objects rotate individually around the individual object centres.

How can I rotate all four objects around the group's centre?

Answer (score 1):

1. Be sure that you group the layers. Select objects and group them `CMD+G`.
2. Enable the rotate function: Layer-> Transform-> Rotate Layer
3. You will find the small cross point in a middle (that actually the anchor that controls the middle rotation for the whole group).

### [image]

4. Move it to the center (after the grouping it should be on a center by default)
5. Rotate

[image: List item]